# Ram Upgrade - Asus Zenbook UX310UQK

Tags: memory, upgrade, zenbook

I have an Asus Zenbook UX310UQK notebook with 8GB builtin ram (soldered on the motherboard).
I would like to upgrade to 16Gb using the only free slot available.

**Can system stability get worse after the upgrade?**

I heard that the best way to upgrade is by matching the exact model number and frequency of the modules that are already installed. Unfortunately I can't match model number because it's soldered but I can match module speed which turns out to be 1.066Mhz (it's the DDR4-2133, right?).

I've attached a screenshot of ram report by hwinfo64.

Thank you very much for the help!

[my notebook ram report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ukd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Stability should not get worse. If you are concerned about errors in your RAM, once you install the new module you can run memtest64 (put it on a bootable USB) to check that all of your ram is good.

Matching the RAM is important for memory performance, but memory performance is not critical. Most software doesn't have a memory performance bottleneck. If you can buy matching RAM, go for it, but don't spend a hundred dollars trying to get something that is an exact match.

Comment: Thank you Andy, got it! One more question: the only 8gb ddr4 2133mhz modules I can find are Crucial and Corsair Value select. I would like to use higher end modules such as Corsair Vengeance or Hyper x impact but they are available only in ddr4 2400mhz version. my cpu (intel core i7-7500u) spec page (https://ark.intel.com/products/95451/Intel-Core-i7-7500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3-50-GHz-) says that higher supported frequecy is 2133 mhz. If I put a 2400mhz module will it be downclocked at 2133 or there are chances that it won't be recognized?

Comment: Actually, you will be offered to overclock the memory controller. This may be hidden as a feature "XMP" or extreme memory profiles. Performance is not guaranteed, but usually works. It mostly comes down to tolerences on your motherboard. Note that all of the modules on the same channel must run at the same speed and timings. I am not certain, but you may be limited by the ram soldered into your system. I would just buy a ddr4 module where one of the tested speeds is ddr4-2133 15-15-15-36

Comment: Note that if you flip through the specifications for your ddr4-2400Mhz ram, it will list slower timings for ddr4-2133. You can buy ram and run it slower than its advertised maximum speed